# Proving $\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{\frac{1}{x}} = 1$ using $\epsilon$ (Cauchy definition for limits)

Tags: limits

I'm trying to prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{\frac{1}{x}} = 1$ using the $\epsilon$ definition of diverging to $\infty$.

My attempt:

(Sorry in advance for English mistakes).

For a given $\epsilon > 0$, I need to find an $M$ so that for every $x>M$:
$$|e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1| < \epsilon$$

I tried the  following:
$$-\epsilon +1<e^{\frac{1}{x}}< \epsilon +1$$
Therefore:

$$\frac{1}{x} > \ln{(1-\epsilon)} \space\space\wedge\space\space  \frac{1}{x} < \ln{(1+\epsilon)}$$

$$x < \frac{1}{ln{(1-\epsilon)}} \space\space\wedge\space\space  x > \frac{1}{ln{(1+\epsilon)}}$$

So that means that in order for the first inequality to be true, $x$ should be within a range dependent on $\epsilon$ that is bounded above... So how can I find such $M$?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $x\to\infty$, we can assume $x$ is positive, so $\frac{1}{x}$ is positive.  Therefore $e^{1/x} > 1$.  So instead of $1-\epsilon < e^{1/x} < 1+ \epsilon$, you can say $1 < e^{1/x} < 1 + \epsilon$.

Given $\epsilon > 0$, it's sufficient to take $M \geq \frac{1}{\ln(1+\epsilon)}$.

Answer (score 4):

In your final step, you divide by $ln(1-\epsilon)$ which is a negative number, so the inequality flips.

I give my own solution.  Define for all positive $x$ a variable $y$ such that $y = \frac{1}{x}>0$, so that our problem turns into

> Prove  $\lim_{y\to 0^{+}} e^y = 1$.  In other words, for every $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $|e^y - 1 |<\epsilon$

Since the exponential function is an increasing function, we have $$ |e^y - 1 |<|e^{0+\delta} - 1|=|e^\delta - 1 | $$ for all $y<\delta$.  The term on the right is less than epsilon if an only if $$1-\epsilon < e^\delta <1+\epsilon$$

But note that $e^\delta > e^0 = 1$ always, so it it is true if and only if $$ 1< e^\delta <1+\epsilon$$ iff $$ 0< \delta <ln(1+\epsilon) $$

Now substitute back $y=1/x$ and $M=1/\delta$